# Get is_read when I'm one of the many message recipients

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by

In my app, users

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

can send messages

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    from_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES users ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    body text NOT NULL CHECK (body <> ''),
    created_at timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT LOCALTIMESTAMP(0),
    is_read boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE
);
```

to many recipients

```
CREATE TABLE message_recipients (
    message_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES messages ON DELETE CASCADE,
    user_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES users ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    is_read boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    PRIMARY KEY (message_id, user_id)
);
```

How do I select messages sent between multiple users such that the `is_read` column specifies whether one of those users has read the messages? I also want to include a column called `to_ids` that contains a comma-separated list of the message-recipient user IDs.

E.g., how do I get the messages sent between users 1, 2, and 3 such that the `is_read` column specifies whether user 1 has read the messages? The `to_ids` column contains two comma-separated IDs from the set `{1, 2, 3}`.

The result set should include the columns: `id, from_id, to_ids, body, created_at, is_read`.

Sample Data

```
SELECT * FROM users;
#  id |  username  | 
# ----+------------+
#   1 | user1      |
#   2 | user2      |
#   3 | user3      |

SELECT * FROM messages;
#  id | from_id |       body          |     created_at      | is_read
# ----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------
#   1 |       1 | This is message 1.  | 2016-12-16 11:41:50 | t
#   2 |       2 | This is message 2.  | 2016-12-16 11:41:50 | t
#   3 |       3 | This is message 3.  | 2016-12-16 11:41:50 | t
#   4 |       1 | This is message 4.  | 2016-12-16 11:41:50 | t
#   5 |       2 | This is message 5.  | 2016-12-16 11:41:50 | t
#   6 |       3 | This is message 6.  | 2016-12-16 11:41:50 | t
#   7 |       1 | This is message 7.  | 2016-12-16 11:41:50 | t

SELECT * FROM message_recipients;
#  message_id | user_id | is_read 
# ------------+---------+---------
#           1 |       2 | f
#           1 |       3 | f
#           2 |       1 | f
#           2 |       3 | f
#           3 |       1 | f
#           3 |       2 | f
#           4 |       2 | f
#           4 |       3 | f
#           5 |       1 | f
#           5 |       3 | f
#           6 |       1 | f
#           6 |       2 | f
#           7 |       2 | f
#           7 |       3 | f
```

Expected Output

```
#  id | from_id | to_ids |       body          |     created_at      | is_read
# ----+---------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+---------
#   1 |       1 |    2,3 | This is message 1.  | 2016-12-16 11:41:50 | t
#   2 |       2 |    1,3 | This is message 2.  | 2016-12-16 11:41:50 | f
#   3 |       3 |    1,2 | This is message 3.  | 2016-12-16 11:41:50 | f
#   4 |       1 |    2,3 | This is message 4.  | 2016-12-16 11:41:50 | t
#   5 |       2 |    1,3 | This is message 5.  | 2016-12-16 11:41:50 | f
#   6 |       3 |    1,2 | This is message 6.  | 2016-12-16 11:41:50 | f
#   7 |       1 |    2,3 | This is message 7.  | 2016-12-16 11:41:50 | t
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Done. :-)